# Too Many query rows in apex class

Tags: apex, batch

while running apex class in salesforce,I am getting too many query rows error

**staging list**:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Name,ECC_Line_Item_Number__c,Delivery_Number__c,ERPId__c,    Customer_PO__c,Route_Description__c,Container_Code__c, CurrencyIsoCode, PAL__c, SalesOrderNumber__c, CustomerID__c, Sub_CustomerID__c, Product_Number__c, OrderedQuantity__c, EquipmentType__c, RequiredDeliveryDateTime__c, Location__c, ActualShipDate__c, ActualLoadDate__c, FreightPC1__c, Shipment_Type__c, SuggestedLoadDateTime__c, ShiptoCity__c, ShiptoState__c, CurrencyIsoCode__c, CarrierName__c, ActualQuantity__c, InvoiceNumber__c, LoadersInitials__c, Batch_Number__c, Grade_Description__c, QuantityUOM__c, ShipFrom__c, Shipfrom_state__c, Integration_date_time_stamp__c, Source_System_Identifier__c, SAP_Order_Type__c, CMIRCustomerMaterialNumber__c, Facility__c, FreightPC2__c, Detailed_Product_Description__c, Status__c FROM Orders_Staging_Table__c where Status__c = \'New\' or Status__c = \'Account Not Available\' order by CreatedDate';
```

Code:

```
Map<string,list<Orders_Staging_Table__c>> staging_erpmap=new map<string,list<Orders_Staging_Table__c>>();


        for(Orders_Staging_Table__c st:staginglist)
        {
            orderStagingTableMap.put(st.id, st);
            if(staging_erpmap.containskey(st.ERPId__c))
            {
                staging_erpmap.get(st.ERPId__c).add(st);
            }
            else 
                staging_erpmap.put(st.ERPId__c,new list<Orders_Staging_Table__c>{st});

        }



list<RelatedEnterpriseRecords__c> erp_information=[SELECT Id, ERP_ID__c, Account__c FROM RelatedEnterpriseRecords__c where ERP_ID__c in: staging_erpmap.keyset()];

            map<String,id> erpaccoutmap=new map<String,id>();
            for(RelatedEnterpriseRecords__c erp:erp_information)
            {
                erpaccoutmap.put(erp.ERP_ID__c,erp.Account__c);
            }




list<order> orderlist=[select id,AccountId,FreightPC__c,Freight_PC2__c,SalesOrderNumber__c,CarrierName__c,CurrencyIsoCode,CustomerID__c,EquipmentType__c,InvoiceNumber__c,ShiptoCity__c,ShiptoState__c,CustomerPO__c,(SELECT Id,Name,Route_Description__c,Container_Code__c, Order__c, ActualQuantity__c,Actualloaddate__c, ActualShipDate__c, AvailableQuantity__c, Batch_Number__c, CMIRCustomerMaterialNumber__c, DetailedProductDescription__c, PriceUOM__c, ShipFrom__c, UnitPrice__c, Facility__c, ECC_Line_Item_Number__c FROM Order_Item__r) from order where AccountId in:erpaccoutmap.values()];
```

Too Many query rows in query.This Query fetching more information:

```
list<order> orderlist=[select id,AccountId,FreightPC__c,Freight_PC2__c,SalesOrderNumber__c,CarrierName__c,CurrencyIsoCode,CustomerID__c,EquipmentType__c,InvoiceNumber__c,ShiptoCity__c,ShiptoState__c,CustomerPO__c,(SELECT Id,Name,Route_Description__c,Container_Code__c, Order__c, ActualQuantity__c,Actualloaddate__c, ActualShipDate__c, AvailableQuantity__c, Batch_Number__c, CMIRCustomerMaterialNumber__c, DetailedProductDescription__c, PriceUOM__c, ShipFrom__c, UnitPrice__c, Facility__c, ECC_Line_Item_Number__c FROM Order_Item__r) from order where AccountId in:erpaccoutmap.values()];
```

> How to restrict the query ?In order to avoid Too Many query rows
>   50,001

Comment: What you are trying to do, its obvious you are getting 50000+ rows , adding a limit will make skip recods and thus make your logic inconsistent

Answer (score 1):

You may need to consider changing your design so that it can be broken across multiple batch jobs that can be run in sequence.  In a nutshell, anytime you run into a situation where a particular job needs to query or update more than 50k records, then you may need a dedicated batch job for it.

The bottom of the this page has a section called [*Chaining Batch Jobs*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) that can help you get started thinking along this path.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown because the maximum number of rows you can return in SOQL calls in Apex is 50000.
The SOQL calls you can be filter with small chunch if your business requirment fullfil.

Or I would suggest you can convert your logic into the asynch call.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the error you can easily add Limit 50000 to the end of your SOQL. However, as stated in Pranay Jaiswal's comment this will make you skip records. I would suggest adding in additional filters into your SOQL's where clause to get the records returned under 50000.

Ex. if you want only need records created in the past few months or days:
CreatedDate = last_n_days:x (x = number of days)
or
CreatedDate = last_N_Months:x (x = number of months)